# Evaluation of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi^{k}(n)}{x^n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I wanted to know whether we have evaluations of series of the form,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi^{k}(n)}{x^n},\ x\ge 2,\ k\ge 1$$
the above is convergent through the comparison test, since we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi^{k}(n)}{x^n}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{x^n}.$$

**Note**: if a closed-form evaluation doesn't exist, I would like to know is it possible to prove that, generally or particularly that the series doesn't evaluate to a rational?

Comment: do you know the evaluation for $x=2,k=1$?

Comment: No, would love to know , if you have/[know of] proof.

Comment: Where does this series come from?

Comment: I don't think a closed form even exists for that case.

Comment: @user155294 As in the motivation of the series??

Comment: @mathworker21 any reason that you suspect that?

Comment: @Sarnak Sahoo Yes. I have a similar series which is related to an open problem.

Comment: This popped up, because I was considering pairs of series such as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s_{n}}{a^n}$$, and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b^n}{s_{n}}$$, where $s_{n}\in\mathbb{Q},\forall n$ somehow I want to disprove the following claim: "Exactly one of the two is rational". **Note**: We have implied that $|b|<|a|$. Can I know what's the open problem??

Comment: A note to the above, the claim is made in addition to the condition that both the series are convergent and therefore we have the implication $|b|<|a|$.

Comment: You could probably calculate $\sum\phi(n)/2^n$ to some large number of decimal places, and then search for the resulting constant.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but in the case $k=1$, one can derive
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\varphi(n)}{x^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(a) x^a}{(x^a-1)^2}.
$$
A similar identity probably holds for $k\geq 2$ as well.